# App Engine – Restrict deploy to specific service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

We have two services running on Google App Engine.

[image: services]

We would like to restrict deployment to only specific users to the default (prod) target, but allow any devs to deploy to dev target.

Can't figure out the IAM conditions for it.

App engine doesn't seem to be an official resource type here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes#resource-name

and it's consistent with the service filter dropdown

[image: dropdown]

I've tried using the *name* i get from `gcloud app services describe dev`:

```
resource.name == 'apps/my-project/services/dev'
```

Bt that doesn't seem to work either, it just gives access denied so guessing that's not the right resource name filter.

Is there a way to limit this as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[App Engine permissions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/roles) are granted at the project level and cannot be filtered for each different service of the application.

There is an open feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/115904598 to allow specific deployments of versions that I recommend you to star and follow.

Separating your prod and dev environments (I understand that this can be inconvenient sometimes) in different GCP projects could be the only viable alternative for the time being.

Comment: LOL! Unfortunately. Feature Requests don't have any ETA, nor guarantee of implementation. In theory the product teams act upon feature requests given the amount of stars and interactions given in a particular thread as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests). I hope that particular feature request gets traction.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't restrict permissions to deploy to specific service because users can create custom services per GCP account.

Two options that I can suggest:

1. Create a different GCP project for prod. If you're using CLI, the prod devs can simply change the GCP project and deploy.
2. Use CICD with Cloud Build, and only grant merge access to prod branch to prod devs. No dev in this case would need access to your GCP projects.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by `users can create custom services per GCP account` ?

Comment: If you're able to deploy, you can create a service called "test", and another can create a service called "test2". It makes less sense to have access controlled per service, and more to restrict the ability to deploy as a whole.

Comment: That's kinda the whole question though

Comment: And my answer was that it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for options, it is possible to accomplish deployment isolation via [`gcloud config`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/configurations/create). It allows the creation of named configuration for each environment, for example.

Configuration governs the behavior of `gcloud` CLI.

Usage example:

### Deploy to DEV (default) environment:

```yaml
deploy:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
  stage: deploy
  environment: Development
  script:
    - cp $GAE_ENV_VARIABLES ./env_variables.yaml
    - echo $GAE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID --version $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA --image-url=us.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

### Deploy to TEST environment :

**you can make it a requirement to have a specific service account to create/activate this environment and even a dedicated `app.yaml` like `app_test.yaml` with different `service` name**.

```yaml
deploy_test:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine
  stage: deploy
  environment: Test
  only:
      - master
  script:
    - cp $GAE_ENV_VARIABLES ./env_variables.yaml
    - echo $GAE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud config configurations create test --quiet --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID 
    - gcloud config configurations activate test --quiet --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID 
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json #activate service account under the new configuration
    - gcloud app deploy app_test.yaml --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID --version $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA --promote --image-url=us.gcr.io/$GCP_PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```